# getting this error Could not instantiate class: com.blazemeter.jmeter.control.WeightedSwitchControllerGui

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I am getting this error when trying to use weighted switch controller in JMeter.
WARN o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate class: com.blazemeter.jmeter.control.WeightedSwitchControllerGui
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null

I am not seeing the Plugin at all in my JMeter

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing your [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)

I can only state that I cannot reproduce your issue using:

- [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/)
- [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/list?user@jmeter.apache.org:2023-7)
- [Weighted Switch Controller 0.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.blazemeter/jmeter-plugins-wsc/0.7)

[image]